# Delete duplicate rows and columns of matrix

Tags: arrays, c

I need to delete (not skip while printing) the rows and columns of a matrix that appear more than once in program, and I should print only first row from the top that appears more than once or the first column from the left that appears more than once.

```
Example input:
1 2 3 2
4 5 6 5
1 2 3 2
7 8 9 8
After deleting:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, j, m, n,row,col, mat[200][200];
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    row = m; col = n;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (mat[i][j] == mat[i++][j++])
            row--;
            if (mat[j][i] == mat[j++][i++])
            col--;
        }
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to make the algorithm work for this task? Mine has mistakes.

Comment: You have stuff like this `if (mat[i][j] == mat[i++][j++]);` notice the semicolon, that means that `row--` and `col--` are always executed

Comment: @pablo fixed :) thanks, do you have any idea for the algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. First thing I would write a function that returns 1 if two columns are the same, 0 otherwise. Then I would iterate over the first column and check if the second column are the same. Is that the case, then remove the second and check with third and keep doing that until you've a column that isn't equal. Then repeat that but now use the second column as your base. Rinse and repeat. Then repeat that for the rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 200
#define COLS 200
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

/*
 * delete k'th row from the m x n matrix
 */
void deleterow(int mat[ROWS][COLS], int m, int n, int k)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = k; i < m - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = mat[i + 1][j];
        }
    }
}
/*
 * delete k'th columns from the m x n matrix
 */
void deletecol(int mat[ROWS][COLS], int m, int n, int k)
{
    int i, j;
    for (j = k; j < n - 1; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            mat[i][j] = mat[i][j + 1];
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int i, j, m, n,row,col, mat[ROWS][COLS];
    int iref, jref;             // reference indexes to compare
    int match;                  // flag to show if the row/col duplicates

    // read input matrix
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    row = m; col = n;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);

    // examine row by row
    for (iref = 0; iref < m; iref++) {
        // compare rows below iref and remove the row if duplicates
        for (i = iref + 1; i < m; i++) {
            match = TRUE;
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != mat[iref][j]) {
                    match = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match) {
                deleterow(mat, m, n, i);
                m--;
            }
        }
    }

    // examine column by column
    for (jref = 0; jref < n; jref++) {
        // compare columns more right than jref and remove the col if duplicates
        for (j = jref + 1; j < n; j++) {
            match = TRUE;
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != mat[i][jref]) {
                    match = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match) {
                deletecol(mat, m, n, j);
                n--;
            }
        }
    }

    // see the result
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf("%2d%s", mat[i][j], j == n - 1 ? "\n" : " ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output with the provided example:

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

**[Explanation]**

As for the operations of rows:

- First, focus on the top row as a "reference". The row is indexed by
  the variable `iref` which is assigned to 0 at first.
- Then compare the remaining rows with the reference, changing
  the row index `i` from iref+1 (just below the reference row) to n-1
  (the bottom row).
- If a row duplicates with the reference, remove the row with the
  `deleterow()` function and decrement the row size `m` by one.
  The modification of `m` affects the `for` loops which compare the
  loop variables with `m`, meaning the matrix size is updated immediately.
  This is a preferable nature of the for loop (IMHO).
- If the comparizon reaches the bottom row, increment `iref` and repeat
  the comparisons again.
- Finally every row has been compared to each other and the duplicates have
  been deleted.

Then perform the similar operations with columns.

Comment: I've updated my answer appending a brief explanation how the code works, just for information.